# Text-To-Speech problem with SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am trying to create a simple text-to-speech application using C# and `System.Speech.Synthesis`. The issue is that I want this application to work with the Greek language. So what I attempted to do is this:

```
SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer
{
Volume = 100,
Rate = -2
};

synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Γειά σου κόσμε!");
```

Of course this does not work, since the result of this code is that the voice  pronounces every letter individually. After a lot of googling, I tried to install and use espeak and the Greek voice that comes with it like this:

```
synthesizer.SelectVoice("eSpeak-el-gr");
```

The result was exactly the same - the voice said every letter individually, and not the whole word. Is there a way to fix this issue, so that `SpeechSynthesizer` will say all the Greek words and not just the letters of them ?

Comment: [SpeechSynthesizer.GetInstalledVoices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.getinstalledvoices).

Comment: I know about this method, but it does not lead me anywhere. The reason is that the pre-installed Greek voice on my computer, does not seem to come up in the list. Take [a look at this screenshot](https://image.prntscr.com/image/E_AwgXUOTp66kswR2K2dyQ.png). I know that I am probably missing something big here, but I do not know what.